# Pre-processing C code with GCC

Tags: gcc, c-preprocessor

I have some C source files that need to be pre-processed so that I can use another application to add Code Coverage instrumentation code in my file.
To do so, I use GCC (I'm using this on a LEON2 processor so it's a bit modified but it's essentially GCC 3.4.4) with the following command line:

```
sparc-elf-gcc -DUNIT_TEST -I. ../Tested_Code/0_BSW/PKG_CMD/MEMORY.c -E > MEMORY.i
```

With a standard file this works perfectly, but this one the programmer used a `#ifndef UNIT_TEST` close and no matter what I do the code won't be pre-processed. I don't understand why since I'm passing `-DUNIT_TEST` to GCC explicitly defining it.

Does anyone have any clue what could cause this? I checked the resulting .i file and as expected my `UNIT_TEST` code is not present in it so I get an error when instrumenting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything wrapped in an #ifndef will only be parsed if it's NOT defined so you need to remove that definition to get all the code that is inside that block. GCC can't spit out preprocessed info for all the #ifdef and #ifndef if at preprocessing times symbols are/aren't defined.

Comment: Thanks Jesus, right after I posted this I understood my problem, it's early morning here :P sorry guys for wasting your time... it was my coder that used ifndef instead of idef ...

Comment: It's ok I've stared down at code before screaming why only to realize it's a dumb mistake.